# Get Comments posted on a page on facebook

Tags: asp.net, facebook, sdk

I am trying to learn using Facebook SDK using ASP.net  I have achieved till now is to get the friend list, athetes pages I like, music i like. Now I amtrying to get the comments that are posted on my time line. What keyword I should use for fetching the comments. I am using following line for fetching friends,favourite athlete, music etc. How do I fetch comments .

dynamic me = fb.Get("me?fields=friends,name,email,favorite_athletes,music,likes");